# Swagger2 configuration spring boot won't working

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui

I'm trying to add swagger to a project and when I access localhost:9999/swagger-ui returns "Whitelabel Error Page" always;

Here is my swagger configuration.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .contact(new Contact("Vinicius Deluca", "", "vinidelucka@gmail.com"))
                .title("Products-ms")
                .description("")
                .license("")
                .licenseUrl("")
                .version("1.0")
                .build();

    }
}
```

This is the first time I use this feature and can't see what I'm doing wrong. See some tutorials and looks like I did all in the same way. But still won't working.

My api runs direct after port 9999, without root package (localhost:9999/products is a get)

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    ProductService productService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Product> productsList() {
        List<Product> products = productService.productsList();
        return products;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Optional<Product> searchProductById(@PathVariable String id) {
        Optional<Product> product = productService.searchProductById(id);
        return product;
    }

    @GetMapping("/search")
    public List<Product> searchProducts(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer min_price,
                                            @RequestParam(required = false) Integer max_price,
                                            @RequestParam(required = false) String q) {
        List<Product> products = productService.searchProducts(min_price, max_price, q);
        return products;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Product> insertProduct(@RequestBody ProductForm form) {
        Product product = productService.insertProduct(form);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(product);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Product> updateProduct(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody ProductForm form) {
        Product product = productService.updateProduct(id, form);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(product);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @Transactional
    public ResponseEntity<Product> deleteProduct(@PathVariable String id) {
        ResponseEntity<Product> response = productService.deleteProduct(id);
        return response;
    }

}
```

application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ProductMsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ProductMsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: for Swagger2 try accessing your page through _http://localhost9999/swagger-ui.html#_. see if that works

Comment: Same issue, return whitelabel error page

Comment: The Docket name (api) is relevant to this work? My project name is "productms"

Comment: Can you share your controller and Application code? the above snippet should work if your GET /products work

Comment: Sure, I will edit the code.

Comment: localhost:9999/products mapping works, and get all entries. all Mappings works actually

Comment: Well, Now I coul made it works.

The version os swagger that I'm using don't be compatible with java11... This Using an older version work correctly.